# Flutter AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() not working

Tags: flutter

#### Question

Hi, I was searching a solution to allow user scroll on a list even when there is insufficient content.
Looking throght Flutter documentation i found this page https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/physics.html

As the documentation said

> To force the scroll view to always be scrollable even if there is insufficient content, as if primary was true but without necessarily setting it to true, provide an AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics physics object, as in:

```
physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

so I tried to run a simple code an detect user scroll even when there isn't enough content

#### code

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

    @override
    void initState(){
      scrollController.addListener((){
        print('listener called');
      });
      super.initState();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 50,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Why this isn't working?

#### edit

Here is the design i'm looking forward

[image]

I have a list that is dynamically created. I want to be able to detect user vertical swipes on that list even if there is no scroll because there aren't enough element to overflow the screen height.

On a scrollable list I can simply add a scroll Listener and then every time a scroll is detected I can do my logic with scrollController.position info's.
I want scroll listener to be called even when user swipes on list of this type

Comment: Can you please explain "scroll on a list even when there is insufficient content"? What is the exact outcome that you're looking for? Is there any design / gif that you can show?

Comment: I edited the thread. Hope I was clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do see the effect of scroll with the addition of **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics** so that part seems to be working. Maybe wrapping the scaffold on a **NotificationListener** can do what you're trying to do:

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

    return NotificationListener(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 50,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
          print('Widget has started scrolling');
        }
        return true;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**NotificationListener** has a property called **onNotification** that allows you to check for different kinds of **scrollNotifications**, you can check more here: [NotificationListener Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) and [ScrollNotification class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Adding Notification Listener allowed me to catch any event.